# How to send a SMB packet with Scapy?

Tags: python, scapy, smb

I'm using the scapy module for sending packets. My goal is to send a smb packet. But sniffing with Wireshark shows me that i'm sending a tcp packet and not smb.

I'm using this template:

```
smb = IP(dst="...",src="...")/TCP(dport=...)/SMBNegociate_Protocol_Request_Header()
```

This packet is sent correctly but wireshark tells me it's simply tcp and not smb (in the protocol field), am i missing something?

Comment: You might want to read about the OSI layer model and you will understand that an SMB packet can be a TCP packet as well.

Comment: try to use the "decode as" option in Wireshark, to tell Wireshark this is an SMB packet. If the decoding fails, this means you did something wrong